# Why do fansubbed animes have a reminder to not sell their fansubbed product?

Tags: copyright

Why do fansubbed animes have a reminder to not sell their fansubbed product? Sometimes they have the following reminder during the show:

> This is a free fansub: not for sale, rent, or auction

I was wondering why that was necessary. Is it so that they do not get into legal problems? What is the purpose of that reminder?

Comment: fansubs are illegal in the first place, i'd assume it it would have something to do with the subbers avoiding any attention drawn to them from ebay auctioneers putting the episodes on DVD and trying to sell them off as the real thing, practically saying "this is a free fansub, we are not responsible for you having paid for it from a third party".

Comment: that disclaimer i find even of brought DVDs though, like "not for resale, rent, public viewing, bla, bla, bla"

Comment: @Memor-X when you say its illegal, what do you mean exactly? If I decide to translate something and put on the internet, if I don't get money out of it, I don't necessarily see why it would be illegal unless there is some specific law saying "you cannot translate anything without the consent of the owners". So I am not sure if you claim is 100% accurate (though I have not looked at any laws in general and would be very interested in seeing exactly what the laws [in some country] say). Also, "illegal" is a relative term varying from country to country, making your claim very ambiguous.

Comment: I think its a very interesting thing to discover where its illegal and why its illegal and under what interpretation of the law its illegal.

Comment: @Pinocchio Copyright infringement. See [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/) (which mostly talks about manga, but the same applies to anime.

Comment: I remember seeing this with older fansubs. I don't remember seeing this for anything newer, like 5 years or something.

Comment: In my experience, though they claim it's meant to avoid legal liability, the reality is that they are upset that others are profiting off their work. It hurts to spend hours and days on a project close to your heart, then see others making money off it.  Adding the notice made it more difficult for re-sellers to profit since their customers would learn that they are watching something they could have for free elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, as most fansubs are done before licensing agreements are established for a series....international copyright may apply, but the real reason is due to fansubbers not wanting to be caught by their countries legal system on licensing violations should the series become licensed.    Now, I am 99% against fansubs, except for ONE case....Macross......seeing as Harmony Gold still clings to the claim they own all licenses to Macross in america from here to eternity, despite Japanese courts saying otherwise....Last macross series licensed in USA was Plus....20 somn years ago /end rant srry

Comment: @NZKshatriya why are you against fansubs? (just curious)

Comment: I am for fansubs of series that have no chance of being licensed due to legal issues.  fansubs walk a fine line between legality and illegality, and can actually lead to a studio not wanting to license a series somewhere.  The Macross situation is so fubar, you can do a search on why new Macross will likely never come to the USA, cos it's a nightmare.   Also, once fansubbed anime gets on file sharing platforms, it's there forever, and cuts into the anime industry in *insert country here*  Anime is a niche industry, and not buying when a series is licensed = not supporting.

Answer (score 26):

I think it's a combination of a few factors.

First, there's a sort of ethical code among some fansubbers that dictates that they fansub for "the love of anime" or something to that effect, and that it's improprietous to profit off of fansubbing. I'm not sure how effective a reminder of this sort would be to people who don't subscribe to the same ethical code (i.e. the people at whom this message would be targeted), but there you have it. Sticking a reminder on your fansubs is pretty much a no-cost endeavor, so it's not like it can hurt.

Then, there's the belief that explicitly stating that you do not intend to profit off of your fansubs makes you less liable for copyright infringement. I doubt this has been tested (I don't know of any litigation against fansubbers), but I rather doubt this would be of much value as a legal defense - statutory damages (as opposed to actual damages) are available in USA copyright infringement cases under federal law (and, I imagine, in other jurisdictions as well).

I suspect (but have no evidence) that this is a holdover from the pre-Internet days of fansub distribution when you actually needed to pass around video tapes to get your anime fix. Exchanging physical materials is likely to get you more scrutiny from law enforcement than exchanging digital information, and this relates to my previous point: infringing copyright is bad, but profiting off of infringed copyrights is probably worse, or at least that's the general perception. [C. Griffin's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9169/1908) to this question contains an interesting view on the matter, from the perspective of someone who consumed fansubs in pre-internet times.

[Adam Davis also brought up in a comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/why-do-fansubbed-animes-have-a-reminder-to-not-sell-their-fansubbed-product#comment11192_9123) another point I meant to address - fansubbers don't want *other* people profiting off of their work - it's kind of a slap in the face. So what's one way to do that? Stick a big "this is not for sale" warning on it, kind of like how a lot of free (gratis) software comes with a notice saying something like "if you paid for this, you should ask for your money back because this is free software".

So here's the problem: basically all fansubbing these days is done with "softsubs" - that is, the subtitles are [basically a text file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ass#Advanced_SubStation_Alpha) that accompanies a video. It's dead easy to edit these things (particularly using software like [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/)), so this is probably another reason that you don't see these disclaimers anymore: they're easy to remove. In the pre-softsub days (maybe before 2008~2010 or so? I don't have my chronology down for this very well), subtitling was done by re-encoding the video to have the subtitles ("hardsubs") baked into the video file. Since this is *much* more difficult to alter, disclaimers would have been more permanent (and hence, useful) back then.

---

Anyway, I haven't seen a disclaimer of this sort on any fansubs from at least the past five years or so - it's gone the way of the dinosaurs. In the modern fansubbing world, where all exchange of fansubs is electronic and hardsubs are obsolete, these disclaimers serve no actual purpose.

(I have seen this sort of thing on recent manga scanlations, though - but that's a topic for another question. The key difference here, I suspect, is that scanlations are still "hardsubbed", so to speak.)

Comment: Aside: Most groups I followed didn't switch to softsubs until 2010-ish, and one still uses hardsubs for some series

Answer (score 12):

I was a *consumer* of fansubs in the early-mid 90's. This statement has no bearing on my answer, however, I was pointing it out because someone thought it would be interesting to hear from a pre-Internet fansub consumer.

All of these answers are valid. Ultimately, the fan sub groups need legal authorities to know that profit is not expected or accepted.  It's a gray area, because the two "products" that we're discussing are the original work (included in a fan sub), and then the translation itself.  The translation can probably be distributed freely, as it is not the same as the original dialogue -- and on its own is an interpretation of a story by a translator.

The iffy part is about the original work being distributed. In most countries, it is illegal to distribute (user-made) copies of copyrighted work without express written consent of the copyright holder. It robs the copyright holder of earnings, blah blah blah. I'm not a legal zealot, and I'm not here to defend any particular side. However, in this day and age, the copyright protections are expected to be upheld in the international community, and enforced by local government or at a higher level -- Interpol.  We don't normally hear about busts like this, because a fansubber usually has a small audience, and many studios secretly find this type of behavior beneficial to increasing their products popularity, and with any luck, profitability.

*Footnote about the pre-Internet days: We would mail our brand new blank VHS cassettes to fansub groups in postage-paid envelopes so that no money would exchange hands whatsoever. It might take a month or two to get your tapes, but for foreign video that was unreleased domestically, it's what you had to do.* </backinthedaystories>

Comment: The translation can be considered a derivative work of copyrighted material and still be shot down. But your historical background is correct.

Comment: The studios still profit from selling merchandising online. International law means Berne Convention, Japan, USA and tons of other countries are signataries. Fansubbed media is still in violation of international law. Its just uneconomical to enforce it.

Answer (score 3):

Even though in some countries, translations of original works are considered original works themselves, the copyright laws are still pretty vague, and so to avoid getting in trouble, fansub groups add such reminders that could be interpreted as "we did not intend to infringe any rights" if they get sued.

So if some shady guy tries to sell some dvds, and they contain very explicit markings of a certain fansub group, that group has some protection by stating that they did not intend for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is largely to do with Copyright issues. You see those who distribute or offer the file are usually in the wrong and violate Japanese copyright laws. But because copyright highly relies on where you are in the world (speaking geographically) fan operated groups who do these fansubs often get away from this and find a way to "turn the other corner".

Even though it is possible to find loopholes such as this, these warnings are often meant to redirect blame if they are sued for infringing on copyright.

Answer (score -3):

I have seen notices that warn that if you have paid money for this fansub you have been ripped off leading me to believe that there have been cases of other parties trying to make money by selling free fansubs and these notices are attempts to stop that.