# English translation for original Getter Robo manga

Tags: getter-robo

I’ve found the complete first series of Getter Robo (the 1974 manga) online, translated in English.

I would love to get a physical copy of this but I can’t find anything to buy, the listings on eBay seem to be for the original Japanese prints.

Does anyone know of a place to obtain this?

Comment: Could you mention where you found it online? Looks like it [hasn't been licensed in English](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nsoxdme/getter-robo) yet, so there's no way to buy it legally.

Comment: Oh that would explain it. I'm kind of new to the manga world, but I'm suprised such an influential series hasn't been published in other languages yet (though I think there's been an Italian translation, but I may be wrong). I will try to find the link to where I found the English version I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Baka-Updates Manga](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/nsoxdme/getter-robo), as of April 2023, *Getter Robo* hasn't been licensed for English audiences yet. Thus, **there are no official copies of the English version** but only unofficial scanlations on the internet which is a complex issue: [What are the legality rules in terms of manga translations?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6471/2516)